# Alternating background colours on Masonry grid

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I'm using a WP plugin that utilises Masonry.js to display posts in a masonry grid. I am displaying 2 rows of three evenly sized 'bricks' and need each 'brick' to have an alternate background colour.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODct7.jpg (Example of what I need)

I've tried to get this working via JS and CSS but it's not happening.

Can anyone provide the best way and a working example?

Thanks

Comment: Would you edit your question to include the JS and CSS so far please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can use css or jquery**

*css:*

```
.block:nth-child(even),.even{background-color:green}
.block:nth-child(odd),.odd{background-color:blue}
```

the `nth-child` selector is paired with a corresponding class of odd/even, so you can use that same css property either way.

*jquery:*

```
$('.block:odd').addClass('odd');
$('.block:even').addClass('even');
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/6Q9UA/

I use both methods in the fiddle, either one will work in modern browsers, but if you're targeting any browsers that an `nth-child` selector won't work in (like <=ie8), then the jquery is a simple fallback.

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you

```
    .yourclass{
    background:blue;
    width:30%;
    height:150px;
    display:inline-block;
  }
 .yourclass:nth-child(2n){

    background:red;
  }
```

in jquery for ie8 and below

```
    $('.block:nth-child(2n)').css({'background-color':'red'});
```

working example http://jsfiddle.net/6Q9UA/12/